# Name of the imported module is not defined within a user defined function python

Tags: python, jupyter-lab

I am trying to reduce the size of a piece of code where I repeat some stuff over and over again. For this purpose, I embedded some lines into a function that were previously working in a module that I called seasonal_adjustment_procedures.py

```py
def seasonal_adjustment(data, subset):
    seasonal_object = {}
    for col in subset: 
        seasonal_object[f'{col}sa'] = sm.tsa.x13_arima_analysis(
            endog = data[col].dropna(), x12path = path_to_x13, 
            prefer_x13 = True)
    return seasonal_object
```

and I call this function as,

```py
from seasonal_adjustment_procedures import seasonal_adjustment
x = {}
x = seasonal_adjustment(mexico_temp, mexico_temp.columns)
```

When I run this on jupyter lab I get this error message,

*name 'sm' is not defined*

I also tried to import statsmodels from within my model yet I get the same error message.

Thanks!

Comment: Error message looks pretty clear. You are using `sm` in the function but it's not defined. You need to define it.

Comment: In seasonal_adjustment_procedures you need to import/define sm

Comment: Did you mean to `import statsmodels as sm`?

Comment: Probably didn't `import statmodels as sm` in `seasonal_adjustment_procedure.py`

Comment: In fact I did try that... and the code works in a plain jupyter notebook but it fails to run when it is in a user defined function

Answer (score 0):

The line `seasonal_object[f'{col}sa'] = sm.tsa.x13_arima_analysis` uses `sm` but nowhere have you defined what `sm` is. I am assuming you took this code from somewhere else?? You mentioned that you have tried importing `statsmodels` but what was likely originally done was

```
import statsmodels as sm
```

That will define sm and should work

Comment: I did that but it does not work... I try to place the import above the def and also inside the def... still get the same error message

Comment: If you are using Jupyter Notebook you need to re-run the cell that the import is in before it takes effect for the rest of your code